# How can I generate spaced grid data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Say I want to generate a series of data such that`[0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.2]...[1, 0.1], [1, 0.2],...[1.5, 1.1],...[2, 1.9], [2, 2]`.

How can possibly I do that without for loop?

Comment: You can use a "while" loop along with a variable, set this variable to a value, say 10, after one cycle of execution then deduct one from 10 until is becomes 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0.1:0.1:2);
Z = [X(:) Y(:)];
```

returns

```
Z =

    0.1000    0.1000
    0.1000    0.2000
    0.1000    0.3000
    0.1000    0.4000
    0.1000    0.5000
    0.1000    0.6000
    0.1000    0.7000
    0.1000    0.8000
    0.1000    0.9000
    ...
```